# Concatenar una vista y un json en laravel

Tags: laravel, json

¿como concatenar una vista y un json en laravel 5?

```
$data = Event::get(['id','title','placa','start']);//variables de json

     //Response()->json($data);

    return view('Calendario.calendario');
```

para poder retornar los 2 al mismo tiempo

Comment: una vista y un json??, exactamente que es lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: lo que pretendo es concatenar la vista y el json como realize en la pregunta normal. tengo un calendario retorno la vista bien pero tambien tengo un json que necesito retornar para poder visualizar la informacion que contiene el json por eso busco la manera de concatenar las 2 cosas .

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas es ajax, o te recomiendo a [mas codigo](https://mascodigo.net/series)

Comment: de hay me estoy basando pero resulta que si vieron ese video el lo realiza en vista principal y siempre esta cargando la vista por defecto y solo tiene que retornar el json y con eso visualiza la informacion pero en  mi caso debo llamar la vista para  luego llamar el json por eso busco la manera de concatenar los dos valores

Answer (score 1):

Tu te refieres a mostrarlo en la vista , entonces seria de esta manera:

```
$data = Event::get(['id','title','placa','start']);
return view('Calendario.calendario', compact('data'));
```

`compact` crea una matriz que contenga variables, en este caso data seria tu variable (ojo que el nombre de variable tiene que ser el mismo que en el `compact`, en este caso `data`)

`data` lo recorres en la vista despues con `blade foreach` quizá.

Comment: No la cuestion es que el json ya contiene la informacion lo que deseo es visualizarlo ya que este metodo es para aplicarlo a un calendario la libreria es full calendar deveria visualizar la informacion me gustaria unir el json como muestro pero solo muestra el calendario  return view('Calendario.calendario',$data);

Comment: etonces mira esto [enlace](https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar)